# How can use higher pandas version when pandas-market-calendars requires lower version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip, dependencies

Upgrade the pandas version:

```
pip install --upgrade  pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.5.3)
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-2.2.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (19 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1.23.2 in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas) (1.26.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas) (2023.3.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.7 in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pandas) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas) (1.16.0)
Downloading pandas-2.2.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.0 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.0/13.0 MB 289.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Attempting uninstall: pandas
    Found existing installation: pandas 1.5.3
    Uninstalling pandas-1.5.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-1.5.3
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
pandas-market-calendars 4.3.3 requires pandas<2.0,>=1.1, but you have pandas 2.2.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed pandas-2.2.0
```

Is there no way to use the pandas-market-calendars then?

```
pandas-market-calendars 4.3.3 requires pandas<2.0,>=1.1, but you have pandas 2.2.0 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: Sometimes you can break the dependencies and everything works well. Here, it seems this is not the case: https://github.com/rsheftel/pandas_market_calendars/issues/315

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when installing a bunch of packages (maybe from `requirements.txt`?) you got an *older* version of `pandas` but the one that satisfies the dependency from `pandas-market-calendars`. Then you tried to upgrade `pandas` alone and got into a conflict.

Sometimes, as @corralien suggested, these version requirements can be disregarded, but not in this particular case. So, until `pandas-market-calendars` is adapted to the current breaking change of `pandas` 2.2.0 there is no way to use the newest `pandas along with` pandas-market-calendars`. I would monitor the 2nd library though as it may get upgraded. Also, you can [file or check tickets](https://github.com/rsheftel/pandas_market_calendars/issues) to see what is that breaking change.